# Custom plugin admin page issues

Tags: wp-admin, options

I have created custom plugin to add admin page as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

I am getting the following warning:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, no array or string given in /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php
>   on line 298.

Here is my code:

```
add_submenu_page( 
    "Add / Edit Price Options in Kilometers",
    "Add / Edit Price Options in Kilometers",
    "Add / Edit Price Options in Kilometers",
    "manage_options",
    "crsc-add-kilometers",
    include( 'admin/template.add-edit-kilometers.php' )
);
```

When the actual page renders, this page's html renders before 'wpcontent' div. I hope this make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter of `add_submenu_page` expects a function callback, not a file include - hence the error as that is not a valid callback. (See [add_submenu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) in the codex.) You can include the file in the function if you prefer:

```
add_submenu_page( 
    "???",
    "Add / Edit Price Options in Kilometers",
    "Add / Edit Price Options in Kilometers",
    "manage_options",
    "crsc-add-kilometers",
    "add_edit_kilometers"
);

function add_edit_kilometers() {
    include( 'admin/template.add-edit-kilometers.php' ); 
}
```

Also, the first parameter needs to be the parent slug menu ID you are adding the submenu to for this to work, you would need to replace `???` above.

Comment: @Krupa no problem, mark as correct answer if you like.